# Blurry screen on Galaxy Note 8.0 (N5110) running CyanogenMod 12

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I have installed CM12 on my Galaxy Note 8.0 (N5110), but now nothing is as sharp as it used to be with original Samsung ROM; all icons, text, etc. are not sharp.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot? Or, by "blur", is it the screen or camera? Lastly, if it's the screen, based on [the same issue on LG Optimus](http://www.hackmyandroid.com/fix-blurred-screen-issue-on-cyanogenmod-9-for-lg-optimus-l3-e400/4156), seems it's related to kernel issue (note: the kernel is for LG, not Samsung, so don't flash it).

Comment: well, its screen...

Comment: Seems there's [transparent blur lock screen on CM](https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/32jzdg/is_it_possible_to_turn_off_the_transparent_lock/). Are you using that? If not, is it always blurry (after unlocking, or when using any apps)?

Comment: no this is not the issue.. The thing is that all icons, fonts etc are not sharp anymore since CM12.. Looks like I bought a cheap china device, but its N5110 and ive used it for 2 yrs..

Comment: Okay, seems the issue is clear enough to be answered. However, I'm not using CM, so I'm not sure I can help (other than pointing that it's probably a kernel issue). Hopefully others can help you.